# java equivalent to printf("%*.*f")

Tags: java, android, printf, string.format

In C, the printf() statement allows the precision lengths to be supplied in the parameter list.

```
printf("%*.*f", 7, 3, floatValue);
```

where the asterisks are replaced with first and second values, respectively.

I am looking for an equivalent in Android/Java; String.format() throws an exception.

EDIT: Thanks, @Tenner; it indeed works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use

```
int places = 7;
int decimals = 3;

String.format("%" + places + "." + decimals + "f", floatValue);
```

A little ugly (and string concatenation makes it not perform well), but it works.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.print(String.format("%.1f",floatValue));
```

This prints the floatValue with 1 decimal of precision

Comment: @BelusC There are both. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29

Answer (score 2):

You could format the format :

```
String f = String.format("%%%d.%df", 7, 3);
System.out.println(f);
System.out.format(f, 111.1111);
```

This will output :

```
%7.3f
111,111
```

You could also use a little helper like this :

```
public static String deepFormatter(String format, Object[]... args) {
    String result = format;
    for (int  i = 0; i != args.length; ++i) {
        result = String.format(result, args[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The following call would then be equivalent as the code above and return `111,111`.

```
deepFormatter("%%%d.%df", new Object[] {7, 3}, new Object[] {111.1111});
```

It's not as pretty as printf, and the input format can become cluttered, but you can do much more with it.

Answer (score 0):

Its like this...

```
%AFWPdatatype
```

`A` - Number of Arguments

`F` - Flags

`W` - Width

`P` - Precision

`String.format("%.1f",float_Val);`