# java prinitng var's issue, sorry for posting same again

Tags: java

so i cant run even such a simple code suddenly:"

```
 public class Test {
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int i=6;
    System.out.println("this is i: %d" ,i);
}
}
```

didnt work with printf either.
same goes for format...etc.

the error im getting is this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
The method println(int) in the type PrintStream is not applicable
for the arguments (String, int) at examples.Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

I dont know what went wrong with the compiler... should i just re instal the eclipse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java equivalent to printf("%\*.\*f")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375768/java-equivalent-to-printf-f)

Answer (score 4):

`System.out.println` accepts only one argument (of any primitive type, `String`, `Object` or array of `char`) and can't print formatted text. You should use `printf` instead:

```
System.out.printf("this is i: %d\r\n" ,i);
```

Comment: still doesnt work! like i said in my question, already tried all your suggestions :\

Comment: @user3443891 works fine, please make sure you copied properly

Answer (score 1):

Java has a different syntax from C

Change

```
System.out.println("this is i: %d" ,i);
```

to

```
System.out.println("this is i: "+i);
```

Concatenating strings and ints is ok in java, and you dont need to specify with %d

You could also use `System.out.printf` just like in C

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("this is i: %d" ,i);
```

While println will take a String, print it and add a new line at the end, printf will take a formatted String and not add a new line at the end. A formatted String means, that you can do stuff like above.

The printf method can be particularly useful when displaying multiple variables in one line which would be tedious using string concatenation.